# Magento 2 : GraphQl error

Tags: magento2, graphql

**The current customer isn't authorized** error appears

Appears on executing mutation in chrome graphQl tool
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/graphql-playground-for-ch/kjhjcgclphafojaeeickcokfbhlegecd

```
mutation {
  revokeCustomerToken {
    result
  }
}
```

any thoughts why this error appearing ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is about a missing authorization token in the request header. The [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/authorization-tokens.html) provides a pretty complete picture about how the token is generated and how it works.

Running the mutation in your example, without setting the authorization token first in the request header, fails because Magento doesn't know which token for which customer to revoke. You can also find the error explained on the **revokeCustomerToken** mutation [documentation page](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/mutations/revoke-customer-token.html).